# Create waiting loading with backdrop in React Native

Tags: react-native

How can I create a loading waiting with backdrop for long tasks in React Native such as ajax call?

I've try using `ActivityIndicatorIOS` in a flexBox `View` with `'absolute'` position but failed. It just show `ActivityIndicatorIOS` at top left of screen.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the style of the View that contains the Activity indicator to

`container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
}`

Here what you are doing is stretching the container to the whole screen and positioning the indicator to the center of the container. Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want the Activity Indicator inside the backdrop and the backdrop just like in HMTL, has fixed position at (0,0) and cover the screen to prevent user click (tap) anything when loading.